# .clientWidth; result is one step behind when triggered by window.addEventListener('orientationchange'

Tags: javascript

I use

```
.clientWidth
```

to detect the width of an image which is then used, amongst other things, to set a div for text so that it is exactly the same dimensions when placed below it.
Whilst this works perfectly on desktop, on mobile devices there is a problem on screen rotation.

My initial javascript was

```
wrapper = document.getElementById("centercontent-wrapper").clientWidth;
imageSize = document.getElementById("catImg").clientWidth;
console.log(imageSize);
var result = (50 / 100) * wrapper;
if (imageSize <= result){
  var element = document.getElementById("cat-desc");
  element.classList.add("ContainerFlex");
  var element = document.getElementById("imageContainer");
  element.classList.add("ImageFlex");
  var element = document.getElementById("textContainer");
  element.classList.add("TextFlex");
}else{
  var element = document.getElementById("imageContainer");
  element.classList.add("text-center");
  var myElement = document.querySelector("#categoryDescription");
  myElement.style.width = imageSize + 'px';
  var myElement = document.querySelector("#categoryDescription");
  myElement.style.margin = "0 auto";
}
```

I added the following to it expecting that the .clientwidth would be updated on orientation change.

```
window.addEventListener('orientationchange', function () {
  console.log("rotate");
  wrapper = document.getElementById("centercontent-wrapper").clientWidth;
  imageSize = document.getElementById("catImg").clientWidth;
  console.log(imageSize);
});
```

It correctly detects orientation change, but the image size is one rotation out.
On initial page load in landscape, image size is detected as 637px.
On initial page load in portrait mode the image size is detected as 345px.

When rotated from portrait to landscape, console shows me that it's been rotated, but still reports image size as 345px. 
After the next orientation change, from landscape back to portrait, console shows image size as 637px.
From then on, console log shows the image size as what it was the last time it was rotated, not this time.

I don't really see why this is happening as console log clearly shows it detecting the orientation change, and it is obviously checking .clientWidth again for it to be logging any change in size at all.

Is this something you have come across before?

Comment: I suspect that the `orientationChange` is firing your handler before the page has been re-processed with the new dimensions (So the width of the element is yet to change). There is a new API called `ResizeObserver` that might fit your case if you are able to use it: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/10/resizeobserver

Comment: I recommend putting all of your code inside a `width:940px; padding:20px; margin:0 auto;` div directly inside your body, using `<meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8' />     <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width' />` tags in your head... I think you can avoid worrying about rotation then, as width is screen width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else that experiences issues similar to this, I resolved it by replacing

```
window.addEventListener('orientationchange', function () {
```

with

```
window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
```

Works perfectly now, instantly recalculating the .clientWidth